# Triangle Construction knowing only parts of 2 sides

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

I have the following triange construction:
The values for $\alpha$, $d$, $a$ and $b$ are known:

[image: Triangle Construction]

I am trying to calculate the angle $\phi$, depending only on $\alpha$, $d$, $a$ and $b$. To archive this, I need to calculate $x$ first. I think, for given values $\alpha$, $d$, $a$ and $b$, there exists a unique solution for $x$. **Is this correct?**

I tried different approaches, for example the *Law of cosines*: $$\cos(\phi) = \frac{(a + x)^2 + (b+x)^2 - (d + a + b)^2}{2 (a + x)(b + x)}$$

or calculating the height $h$: $$h = \sin(\alpha) (a + x)$$ to later use  the *Pythagorean theorem*.

Can you give me a hint, how to calculate $x$, such that I can calculate $\phi$ later? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

By law of cosine we have

$$(b+x)^2=(a+x)^2+(d+a+b)^2-2(a+x)(d+a+b)\cos \alpha$$

Comment: I tried this just now. Do you think it is possible to get a solution like $x = ...$?
For me, it seems it is not possible to extract $x$. The best I can do is: $$(2d + 2a + 2b) cos(\alpha) = \frac{2 a^2 + 2 a x + d^2 + 2 a d + 2 b d - 2 b x}{a + x}$$, but it is not even close to get a solution for $x$ I guess.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes it should be possible, the $x^2$ terms cancel out and we have a linear equation in x.